# Visualization of an oscillation lemma

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, regularity

How can one visualize Theorem 4.2 on page 31 of [this paper by  Seregin, Silvestre, Šverák and Zlatoš](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.6025.pdf)?

On the other hand, I have a clear visualization of a related result about how oscillation decay implies Hölder regularity (which is illustrated, for example, in Figure 2.2 on page 30 of [Fernández-Real and Ros-Oton's lecture notes](https://www.ub.edu/pde/xros/Llibre-ellipticPDE.pdf)).